# Oracle Table Partitioning

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, partitioning

Suppose i have following table:

```
Table Name: ITEM
Columns: ID, ITEM_NUM, ITEM_COLOR, ITEM_SPEC, ITEM_STATUS
```

And the ITEM Table is (LIST) partitioned on ITEM_STATUS Column.
The only values ITEM_STATUS can have are: *Active, Inactive, Suspended*
ID is the PK, therefore there is index on it.

Now, when i execute this Query:

```
select * from ITEM where ITEM_COLOR="Green"
```

Please help me with
1. How will Oracle determine which Partition to go to, since the Partition is NOT on ITEM_COLOR column? 
2. Will the above Query not benefit from Partitioning at all?
3. Is it necessary for SQL Queries to have the Partitioned Column in WHERE Clause for it to benefit from Partitions.
4. How to use Indexes in case of Partitions?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no way to determinate if your query needs just data coming from specific partitions, Oracle must look at all partitions of your table.

The concept of partition can't be well explained with a simple answer, it would be better to read documentation to have a good understanding.

Anyway before getting into this be sure to have performance problems first, if not leave the tables unpartitioned.

Go to

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/parpart.htm#i1007993
or
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16541/part_admin001.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Think at your partitioned table as three tables. ITEM_active, ITEM_inactive, ITEM_suspended.
Phisically there are three tables. Logically you have one table.

So, when you ask for one colour, you need to scan all three tables, because green items may be Active or not, or suspended. With other words, you won't benefit from partitioning for this query.

Question 3: No. Partition schema shoud be transparent for queries. I would specify: The queryes must be independent to partitions(That is, don't specify partition names but use where clause to filter data). A query that ask for Suspended Items will benefit implicitly from partitioning: will scan only the partition wich contains suspended items.

Question 4: Indexes may be global( a single index object over all partiitons - harder to maintain) or local (a phisical index for every partition). Indexed columns benefit for fast search using index. There is nothing special with partitioned indexes.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it won't use the partition pruning, (This is selecting only one partition to know where to retrieve the information), and will go in all the partitions.
Of course, if you don't use the ITEM_STATUS, oracle can't use only one partition.

Your query won't benefit from partitioning.

You don't need to put the partitioned column in the where clause, you could use `FROM table partition (ACTIVE)`.

You can use partitioned index, or normal indexes.